# ThreadPoolExecutor Exception Notification

Tags: java, exception, threadpoolexecutor

Can you please help me validating this piece of code. I am trying to perform some file download task simultaneously. And later if all the download are successfully only then i am suppose to post-process them. If any of the task failed i should be throwing the exception to the caller, as i don't want to post process semi successful results.

Here is my custom ThreadPoolExecutor where i try to check for any exceptions from any thread in the pool

```
public class CustomExecutorePool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

private AtomicBoolean errorFlag = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public CustomExecutorePool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
        long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory);

}


@Override
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable childThreadException){
    if(null != childThreadException){
        logger.error("Exception occurred in one of the child threads: >>> " + childThreadException.getMessage() );
        errorFlag.set(true);
    }
}

public AtomicBoolean isErrorPresent(){
    return errorFlag;
}
```

As you can see i try to use an AtmociBoolean flag and set it to true if any of the child thread has an exception.

And here is the snippet from my main class where i try to use this information :

```
ThreadPoolExecutor docFetchingThreadPool = new CustomExecutorePool(...)
    try {
        // populate the thread pool queue for all the runnables to fetch documents
        for(Document myDoc : list){
            docFetchingThreadPool.execute(myDoc);
        }

        logger.info("All docs added to the work queue");
        docFetchingThreadPool.shutdown();
        logger.info("Waiting to finish work queue task for 3 mins");
        docFetchingThreadPool.awaitTermination(3, RETREIVAL_WAIT_UNIT);


        if(docFetchingThreadPool.isTerminated() && 
                !(docFetchingThreadPool.isErrorPresent().get()){

            //sucessfull post-process all docs now
            //......
        }else {
            throw new MyException("Exception occured in fetching");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("Interrupt exception received ", e);
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new MyException("Interrupt exception");
    } finally {
        if(null != docFetchingThreadPool){
            logger.info("Force shoutdown for residual threads if any...");
            docFetchingThreadPool.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
```

Can you please let me know if this looks okay, or will the error boolean flag will have any synronization issues or is this even the correct way to  go about.
I am aware of using the invokeall function on the executor service, but still debating which  one will be a cleaner approach for handling any exception scenarios.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: look not bad, you can use a `volatile boolean` instead of AtomicBoolean too, also I'm a little confused about `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` what is this for when you thrown an exception too?

Comment: You are right i dont think i need the interrupt in the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't subclass ThreadPoolExecutor. In particular, this makes the thread pool usable only for one execution of a set of tasks.

When you submit a task to a thread pool, you get a `Future` back from the thread pool. So you simply need to iterate through the returned futures, `get()` their result, and do whatever you want if any of the get method throws an ExecutionException (meaning that the task itself threw an exception, wrapped inside the ExecutionException).

Comment: I only want to use the thread pool for a given request. If a new request comes in, i will be using a new instance of this executor, as every request needs to be parallelized with its own set of child threads, makes sense ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The whole point of a thread pool is to be a pool of reusable threads. It's meant to be reused again and again.

Comment: do you see any problems with my current approach. I was trying to avoid the iterator over all the futures, as my runnable will be already populating my file readers with an inputstream so no need of get() as such

Comment: What's not clear in "You shouldn't subclass ThreadPoolExecutor"? Yes, I think it's the wrong approach. What I think you should do is written in my answer. Even if your tasks don't return anything, you may call get(). It will return null, which is the sign that the task succeeded. If it throws an ExecutionException, it indicates that the task thrw an exception, wrapped inside the ExecutionException.

Comment: I see what where you getting at, i will fix this code to use invokeAll() along with get() to look for the executionexceptions and completed tasks. BUT, is it okay to shutdonw the current executor after all my tasks are completed, for a given main servlet request. As i want every user request to have it own set of threads, who can serve it.

Comment: You can do that, but why would you? The two main points of a thread pool are to reuse threads instead of creating new ones (because creating threads takes time), and to make sure the number of threads stays below a reasonable maximum (to avoid going out of memory and/or bringing your system to its knees). By creating a new thread pool for each request, you lose these two advantages.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, i will try to refactor to use single pool and see how it goes.